# How can I make Leaflet controls stack horizontally rather than vertically?

Tags: leaflet

I have the zoom control and the scale bar in the bottom left corner.

The problem I have is that when my map is rotated on mobile, they overlap with a custom control panel in the top left corner.

[image: Example of rotated map view]

So how can I make the scale bar sit horizontally next to the zoom control?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by changing the css for the scale control. By default, controls on the left side of the screen will be styled as `display:block` and `float: left`, but if you add this to your css, the scale should display inline with the zoom control:

```css
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control-scale {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```